# Phrases for conclusion in an essay

Tags: phrases, expressions, writing-style, formality

I want to start the conclusion of my essay by using

> So, to sum up …
>   or
>   To sum it up, …

Do you think they are formal and stylish?

Comment: This question may be simple, and asking for writing advice BUT it is also very useful to visitors. At least this is not about proofreading an essay. There are also other ways to begin the conclusion of an essay, which should be mentioned in answers.

Answer (score 3):

The first is right, the second sounds awkward.

Formal, yes. Stylish, no. Pretty standard really, which is good, because you don't necessarily want to be fancy here. It's what you say next that will count.

You could also say *In conclusion* or *To conclude* or *As we have seen* or *As I have shown* or *In discussing these matters what has emerged is...*

Answer (score 1):

It is formal, but I would not consider it stylish. I try to avoid using phrases such as "In conclusion", "To wrap it all up", or anything similar. I prefer to reiterate the thesis and the main points of the paper, then have a strong finishing sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I' d use *to conclude*;  to sum up sounds  a bit informal to me, though correct.

Comment: Asghar, are you looking to use a peroration style?                                                                                                          Peroration
    n. the concluding part of a speech, forcefully summing up what has been said.

    * * *
    noun
    1. a flowery and highly rhetorical oration                                                    http://useful_english.enacademic.com/99654/peroration